# Implementing Dependency Injection from a new file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I`ve been working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC project and it is working as expected, the only issue i'm having right now is the size of the Startup.cs file, i'm using the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection a lot, and it's very good!, but as i mentioned it is getting very crowded with those "services.AddTransient, Scoped or Singleton", is there a way to create my own class to add those services and call it from the Startup.cs?.

So far i've been trying to make a static class with an "Inject" method that will return an IServiceCollection, but it is not working, i've been searching on google for some examples but it looks like this is not a "thing".

Let me share some sample code:

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Models;

namespace MyFirstAzureWebApp
{
    public class Injections
    {
        private static readonly IServiceCollection _services;

        public static IServiceCollection Inject()
        {
            
            _services.AddTransient<IValidator<Customer>, CustomerValidator>();
            _services.AddTransient<IValidator<Requirement, RequirementValidator>();
         _services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
            _services
                .AddFluentEmail("noreply@myownmail.com")
                .AddRazorRenderer()
                .AddSmtpSender("smtp.myownmail.com",445);

            return _services;
        }
    }
}
```

And at the Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddFluentValidation(opt => 
                {
                    opt.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
                    opt.ValidatorOptions.LanguageManager.Culture = new CultureInfo("es");
                });

            //Dependency Injetions call
            services = Injections.Inject();
}
```

I hope this information is enougth to bring some light over my problem.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you absolutely can do that. I use it all the time to keep my code nice and clean. You can easily do it with Extension methods:

```
public class Injections
{

    public static IServiceCollection RegisterServices(this IServiceCollection services) => services
        .AddTransient<IValidator<Customer>, CustomerValidator>()
        .AddTransient<IValidator<Requirement, RequirementValidator>();
        
    public static IServiceCollection AddOtherServices(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) =>  services
        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"])
        .AddFluentEmail("noreply@myownmail.com")
        .AddRazorRenderer()
        .AddSmtpSender("smtp.myownmail.com",445);
    
}
```

Then in your `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddFluentValidation(opt => 
            {
                opt.DisableDataAnnotationsValidation = true;
                opt.ValidatorOptions.LanguageManager.Culture = new CultureInfo("es");
            });

    //Dependency Injetions call
    services.RegisterServices();
    services.AddOtherServices(Configuration);
    
}
```

Comment: Yes... this one worked really well!, there was some small issue with the "AddOtherServices", i was getting this error "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.FluentEmailServicesBuilder' to type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection'.", so i decided to leave it out and just use the "RegisterServices" since that is the biggest so far. Thank you very much for the help @user15119845

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a common thing (because yes - it does get crowded!).

One approach is to write extension methods on [IServiceCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.iservicecollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) grouping bits of functionality together.

For example, you might create a file called `DatabaseServices.cs`, which adds entity framework or Dapper or whatever.

```
// DatabaseServices.cs
public static class DatabaseServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddDatabases(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
         // Set up Entity Framework
         services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(/* configure EF */);
         
         // Do other stuff related to databases.

         // Return the service collection to allow chaining of calls.
         return services
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup.cs` you can just do:

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddDatabases();
```

Create other files to add logging, configuration, services, HTTP clients, etc. etc.